# How does WPF window page navigation work?

Tags: c#, xaml

I am trying the Pivot Control example.

In my xaml file, it has

```
<PivotItem
    x:Uid="PivotItem2"
    Margin="19,14.5,0,0"
    Header="Their Lists"
    DataContext="{Binding TheirLists}"
    d:DataContext="{Binding Groups[1], Source={d:DesignData Source=/DataModel/SampleData.json, Type=data:OneListDataSource}}">
    <!--Double line list no text wrapping-->
    <ListView
        ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
        Loaded="SecondPivot_Loaded"
        ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo.ExitElementContainer="True">
        ....
```

In the function `ItemView_ItemClick()`, it has:

```
private void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
    // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
    var itemId = ((OneList.Data.OneList)e.ClickedItem).UniqueId;
    if (!Frame.Navigate(typeof(ItemPage), itemId))
    {
        throw new Exception(this.resourceLoader.GetString("NavigationFailedExceptionMessage"));
    }
}
```

I need help in understand how this will end up constructing 'ItemPage.xaml'?

Where in the solution which ties `ItemPage` will be created when an item is clicked?

Comment: The `Frame.Nagivate` ties `ItemView` to the `ItemPage`.  It's responsible for creating a new (or reusing an existing) `ItemPage` instance.

Comment: BTW, your question isn't about C# page navigation. It's about WPF page navigation. The language is not relevant.